# OAuth authentication with Twitter's API using R

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, roauth

I am exploring the Twitter API.

I am using the `ROAuth` and `twitteR` packages in R.

I reach a point where I think things are going well:

```
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=XXXXX
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here: XX
```

So far so good.  Now, I am ready to see some Twitter timelines:

`> my_tweets <- userTimeline('someTimeline')`

Unfortunately, I get:

```
Error in InterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) : 
  OAuth authentication is required with Twitter's API v1.1
```

I have been researching what this means.  I feel like my OAuth authentication is appropriate.  Why would I be getting this error?

Is there some issue with the version of the API I am using?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this step:

```
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "Mjn6tdsadsadkasdklad2SV1l"
consumerSecret <- "58Z7Eldsdfaslkf;asldsaoeorjkfksaVCQtvri"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=reqURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake()
```

After you run this code you will see in R console message like this :

```
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=scmVODruosvz6Tdsdadadasdsa
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here:
```

Just paste the link to your browser then authorize app, last one you will get the PIN code, just copy and paste the PIN code to your R console.

```
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
```

R console will show TRUE if you success.

```
user <- getUser("xxx")
userTimeline(user, n=20, maxID=NULL, sinceID=NULL, includeRts=FALSE)
```

If still any problem just try to show your package version and update to the last version

```
sessionInfo()
update.packages("twitteR")
```

The last version for twitteR is 1.1.7 => http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I see that you were successful accessing (aka handshaking). I assume your handshaking code would be similar to the following line.

```
Cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "your_certificate.pem", package = "RCurl") )
```

Then I assume you registered Twitter OAuth by using the following line, which you said that it was successful.

```
registerTwitterOAuth(Cred)
```

Then your **userTimeline** should include the **pem** file you created before.

```
my_tweets <- userTimeline('someTimeline', cainfo="your_certificate.pem", n=200)
```